# I get empty data on the datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, localdb

I'm trying to pass value from a SQL Server localdb database to a datagridview by textbox.

I use this code:

```
 Public Sub InsertBarcode()
        Dim x As Integer
        Try
            If Con.State = 1 Then Close()
            Con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from Products where ProdBarCode=@ProdBarCode", Con)
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdBarCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtBarcode.Text
            Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If dr.HasRows Then
                While dr.Read
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                    x = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                    DataGridView1(0, x).Value = dr("ProdId").ToString
                    DataGridView1(1, x).Value = dr("ProdName").ToString
                    DataGridView1(2, x).Value = dr("QtyAvailable").ToString
                    DataGridView1(3, x).Value = dr("BuyPrice").ToString
                End While
                dr.Close()
                Con.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("There is no data")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
Private Sub TxtBarcode_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles 

TxtBarcode.PreviewKeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            InsertBarcode()
            'TxtBarcode.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```

I get just the first row and when I try to add another barcode or the same barcode, I get empty rows.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to use DataTable() instead of a While ... End While

```
Public Sub InsertBarcode()
    Dim x As Integer
    Try
        If Con.State = 1 Then Close()
        Con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from Products where ProdBarCode=@ProdBarCode", Con)
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdBarCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtBarcode.Text
        Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            'While dr.Read
            '    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
            '    x = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            '    DataGridView1(0, x).Value = dr("ProdId").ToString
            '    DataGridView1(1, x).Value = dr("ProdName").ToString
            '    DataGridView1(2, x).Value = dr("QtyAvailable").ToString
            '    DataGridView1(3, x).Value = dr("BuyPrice").ToString
            'End While
            'dr.Close()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            dt.Load(dr)
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            Con.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("There is no data")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```